# Socket returns '[Object object]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, socket.io

ive tried for hooours and cant find any solution, im trying to parse data to my server file which puts the content to a mysql database, but its always only outputting [object Object] and i seriously cant find any solution for this. Would appreciate any help.

Main.js

```
   "use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect(":2096");
        var s = socket;
        function connect() {
                if (!socket) {
                    if (hash == "" || hash != "") {}
            socket = io(":2096");
            s.on('connect', function() {
                if (hash != "") {}
                s.emit('hash', hash);
            });
        }
}
    connect();
});
$(document).on('click', '.adm-req', function(data) {
    var name1 = $('#firstname');
    var lastname = $('#lastname');
    var userid = $('#userid');
    var pin = $('#pin');
    var password = $('#password');
    socket.emit('--get-request_adm', {
        firstname: name1,
        lastname: lastname,
        userid: userid,
        pin: pin,
        password: password
    });  
});
```

Server.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var md5 = require('md5');
var sha256 = require('sha256');
var math = require('mathjs');
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var httpServer = require('https').createServer(options, app)
var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
httpServer.listen(2096);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    socket.on('--get-request_adm', function(data) {
        pool.query('INSERT INTO `users` SET `firstname` = "'+data.firstname+'"')
    });
});
function query(sql, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
        callback = function() {};
    }
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            connection.release();
            return callback(null, rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the `[object Object]` coming from? Which line in which file?

Comment: `$('#firstname')` is a jQuery Object - you want the **val**ue of that input, no doubt ... so `var name1 = $('#firstname').val()` - repeat for ALL your inputs

Comment: @JackBashford Its the output to the mysql database. Instead of inputting the text from the input its just inputting [object Object].

Comment: @JaromandaX Exactly how do you mean? im alreay using var name1 = $('#firstname'); as u can see

Comment: exactly as I said, that returns a jQuery object ... not the value of the input you seek - did you stop reading after about 3 words and decide I don't know what I'm talking about? did you read the part where I said you need to use `$('#firstname').val()` instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes sorry i didnt understand what u ment at first, but now it works, thanks! :)

Comment: all good - I just realised I edited the comment anyway :p

Comment: Also the server side code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please take care of it if you are building a production app.

Comment: @Hassaanz Yes im aware about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this

```
var name1 = $('#firstname');
// etc
```

That returns a jQuery **object** - which is why the string value is `[object object]`

Try getting the **value** of the inputs (assuming they are inputs of course) using jquery.val()

```
$(document).on('click', '.adm-req', function(data) {
    var name1 = $('#firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
    var userid = $('#userid').val();
    var pin = $('#pin').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    socket.emit('--get-request_adm', {
        firstname: name1,
        lastname: lastname,
        userid: userid,
        pin: pin,
        password: password
    });  
});
```

alternatively, if you need the jQuery objects for some other reason

```
$(document).on('click', '.adm-req', function(data) {
    var name1 = $('#firstname');
    var lastname = $('#lastname');
    var userid = $('#userid');
    var pin = $('#pin');
    var password = $('#password');
    socket.emit('--get-request_adm', {
        firstname: name1.val(),
        lastname: lastname.val(),
        userid: userid.val(),
        pin: pin.val(),
        password: password.val()
    });  
});
```

Comment: Ohh yeah i see what you mean now, yes ofcourse.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `val`ue of `firstname`, not the object itself - so obtain this when you declare it:

```
var name1 = $('#firstname').val();
```

Do this for all your declarations to get the value.